# How to hide or remove state/province field from billing page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, billing, state

Hi guys i am new to magento.While dealing with the billing page in one page checkout i faced some troubles.There is state/province field which goes hide when page completely loads.When i inspect the page there is a console error "qwertykart.com/:792 Uncaught TypeError: $j(...).foundation"

In order to solve the error deleting state/province is better i think.Can anyone help me to remove it from billing page.

Thanks in advance.I searched a lot on this but didnt find a good solution/working solution thankyou..

check this link after adding item to cart http://qwertykart.com/checkout/onepage/index/

Comment: do you want in shipping address ? or want to remove from both

Comment: bro can you start a chat

Comment: come on this http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40481/room-for-ashish-madankar-and-siby-xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is with reference to chat.

as you are using custom theme which have made changes in **billing.phtml** which breaks a default functionality of magento. compare the file with default theme RWD package and find out the unwanted code from it and make sure that all default id's and form's must be present their.

remove unwanted scripts from the code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: :bhai are you free now?

Comment: for 20 min only

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117654/cant-add-product-and-manage-categories-in-admin-panel please help me..

Comment: updated the answer please have a look on it.