# Can't add product and manage categories in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, admin-panel

Hi guys i am new to magento.while doing update to site.I figured out a abnormal error Can't add product and manage categories.It shows nothing.But the product that have already added have no problem they can be editable.what whould i do.Please help me.

[image]

[image]

nothing is showing...
Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Comment: You'd post concrete errors, so people can help you to fix them. Here you have a nice post to learn to debug & find errors http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their might be a problem with combine java script. set **Merge JavaScript Files to No**.

For this navigate to system->configuration

Then under Advanced->Developer and **JavaScript Settings**

Hope this help you.

Comment: bro you are so Great..

Comment: Thankyou so much............

Comment: i can see your smile keep smiling :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, but i also wanted to merge js files for front-end.

So what i did was, i disabled js merge for admin and enabled it only for front-end.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/160874)

Comment: i think it does, please read the question and then my answer. Hopefully it will make sense.